# What is "Rasetsu"?

Tags: japanese-language, anime-history

I come across the term "Rasetsu" in Japanese games and anime, but I can't find a specific kanji or translation of term.

According to [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com.br/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=Rasetsu&op=translate), "Rasetsu" in Japanese means "Rasetsu" in English.
[image]

I know it has to do with undead, zoombies and vampires, but I don't have a clear and precise concept.

So, for example, currently, I am watching Hakuouki, which has a Rasetsu Squad.
[image]

Some animes where the term "rasetsu" appear:

- Rurouni Kenshin: In this anime, there is a character named Makoto Shishio who is often associated with the term "rasetsu".
- Tokyo Ravens: Onmyouji has the ability to summon and control spirits, including Rasetsu.
- Ayakashi: Samurai Horror Tales: Includes a Rasetsu as a vengeful spirit.

Some games where the term "rasetsu" appear:

- Muramasa: The Demon Blade: Rasetsu as challenging boss characters that the player encounters throughout the game.
- Toukiden series: This action RPG features various types of demonic creatures, including rasetsu.
- Nioh: Includes rasetsu as dangerous enemies that players must confront.

So the question is, in anime, manga, and games, what or who is Rasetsu?

Comment: I'll note that Google Translate assumes that you're inputting text in the appropriate alphabet, so using the English alphabet to input Japanese won't work.

Comment: https://translate.google.com.br/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E7%BE%85%E5%88%B9&op=translate @ConMan same thing.

Comment: Fair enough, this is clearly one of those cases where there isn't a simple English translation so it isn't particularly helpful - although it does also list "Rakshasa" as an alternative translation option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rasetsu (羅刹) is the Japanese Buddhist term for Rākshasas.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakshasa):

> Rākshasas ... are a race of usually malevolent beings prominently featured in Hindu mythology. They reside on Earth but possess supernatural powers, which they usually use for evil acts such as disrupting Vedic sacrifices or eating humans
>
> Many Rakshasas appear in various Buddhist Scriptures. In Chinese tradition rakshasa are known as luocha (羅刹/罗刹).[18] In Japan, they are known as rasetsu (羅刹).

I am not Buddhist so I may be lacking some cultural context, but they tend to appear in fiction as demons who consume the flesh of humans or those who are sent to hell.